# Wordpress multisite: how to set front page in sub sites?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have created sites under wordpress multisite. But all subsites homepages are set to posts. It is not even showing Front Page option to set in Setting->Reading. How can i set homepages for those subsites

Comment: Do you have at least one page on your subsites ?